# Use operators within a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to add variables to some of the values within an array. Simply, I want to do this:

```
var a = prompt("Enter either PNG or JPG");
var array = ["foo." + a, "bar." + a,"vid.oog"];

var x = prompt("Which image to display?");
document.getElementById('imge').src=array[x]
```

It doesn't let me; it simply returns "undefined" Is there any way to do it? I don't want to define a bunch of variables, then stick those variables into the array. Nor can I just simply add "+ a" to the end of the last line, because that will cause the third element in the array to be "vid.oogjpg" or "vid.oogpng".

I know in Python you can do this. Sadly, not JS though.

Comment: why not create the elements before hand, and then add them to the array?

Comment: Should work as is - eg: http://jsfiddle.net/2PVLK/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare your array like this:

```
var array = ["foo","bar","vid.oog"]; // leave them without extension it will be added later.
```

and then you can do this:

```
array.map(function(x){
  return  x.indexOf('.') == -1 ? x + "." + a : x; 
});
```

Comment: Would be nice if you explained it.

Comment: @user3138189, it goes through each item and then checks if it contains extension otherwise it adds the user provided extension to it.